# Questions about pmf of multinomial distribution with indicator variables

Tags: distributions, density-function, multinomial-distribution

I was reading through the textbook of Introduction to Machine Learning, it introduces $z^{t} = (z_{1}^{t},...,z_{k}^{t})$, where $z_{i}$ is an indicator variable, each with probability $\pi_{i}$, then the textbook gives the expression for the pmf for z: $p(z) = \prod_{i}^{k}\pi_{i}^{z_{i}^{t}}$.

I would like to know the detailed derivation of this formula, my concern is that according to this formula below, there should be another term in front of the product term.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sequence of Bernoulli (indicator) random variables $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,...$ with respective probabilities $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3, ...$ then for the sample vector $\mathbf{z}_k = (z_1,...,z_k)$ the probability mass function should be:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p_\mathbf{Z}(\mathbf{z}_k | \boldsymbol{\pi})
\equiv \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{Z}_k = \mathbf{z}_k | \boldsymbol{\pi}) 
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}(Z_i = z_i | \pi_i) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \text{Bern}(z_i | \pi_i) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \pi_i^{z_i} (1-\pi_i)^{1-z_i}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$